# Any way to pass an object from c# code behind to javascript?

Tags: c#, javascript

I want to pass an object from my c# code behind to my javascript. I know that I can use

```
var myVar = '<%# myVar %>'
```

to pass variables. However, that method seems to pass everything as a string. I want an object.

Is there any way to accomplish that?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can serialize it to JSON using the `JavaScriptSerializer`.

Something like:

```
System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer oSerializer = 
         new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();

string sJSON = oSerializer.Serialize(myVar);
```

Then you in your aspx code you can use:

```
var myVar = <%# sJSON %>;
```

Which will output something like:

```
var myVar = {"Name":"John","Age":"30","ID":"111"};
```

Comment: Argument for using `var` on the `oSerializer` instantiation but good answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use JSON serialization to convert a .NET object into JS which can be deserialized into an object (or, exec'd into an object).