# Render C# class as javascript

Tags: c#, javascript

I'm looking for a way to render a C# class object to javascript. For instance this class definition:

```
public class Foo
{ 
   public string Bar1 { get; set; }
   public string Bar2 { get; set; }
}
```

should render (an object of class Foo with values filled) as:

```
foo: 
{
    bar1: 'bar1value',
    bar2: 'bar2value'
}
```

I know my way around reflection, but before reinventing the wheel all over again I was wondering if there are any libraries already doing these kind of things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might do what you want: http://json.codeplex.com/

There's an example as well: http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/

If I recall, JSON demands quotes for key names (though probably tolerates a lack thereof), but I wasn't sure about Javascript, so I tested it with the following HTML, which seems to be usable in Chrome, IE, and Firefox.

```
<html>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        o = { "a":1, "b":2 };
        alert(o.a +" " +o.b) ; 
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Hopefully, you'll be able to use such syntax directly ([RFC 4627](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt) says that JSON is a subset of Javascript).

Comment: That's exactly what I needed, thank you very much. Perhaps you have an answer to my follow up question too? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028069/json-net-ignoring-class-with-only-null-properties

Comment: Welcome. I'm not sure my answer to your other question will help too much, though.

Comment: Hmmm actually I'm not quite sure if this is indeed what I need. The difference: json.net outputs foo { "bar1": "bar1value" } where I need: foo { bar1 : "bar1value" } (note the missing quotes). If I need to do lot's of custom things to get it working, I'm better off writing my own serialization handlers.

Comment: I've added a sort of a test case. The quote syntax also works with [Rhino](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/).

Comment: Yeah, it seems it doesn't really matter if there are quotes or not. So I'm now using the code with quotes and that seems to work ok. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can serialize your object to JSON.

See my answer here : [Any way to pass an object from c# code behind to javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7846333/any-way-to-pass-an-object-from-c-sharp-code-behind-to-javascript/7846374#7846374)

Answer (score 0):

You're probably trying to pass a C# object to the view through post.

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GetDataController(
    string param1,
    string param2) 
{
    var myFoo = new Foo
    {
        Bar1 = "Param1 is: " + param1,
        Bar2 = "Param2 is: " + param2
    };

    return Json(myFoo);
}
```

And now, on your view, request the object through ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    datetype: 'json',
    url: '@Url.Action("GetDataController")',
    data: {
        param1: "line1",
        param2: "line2"
    },
    success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
        alert("I've received this JSOn object:\n\n" + data);
    },
    error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrow) {
        alert("Error while requesting JSON");
    }
```

Comment: this answer is too specific to MVC.

Comment: Ups, you're right! I though I had arrived here through one of favorited tags *asp.net-mvc-3*.

Comment: Nope, not creating controller logic!

Answer (score -1):

```
 Dim RegisteredUsers As New List(Of Person)()
        RegisteredUsers.Add(New Person With {.PersonID = 1, .Name = "Bryon Hetrick", .Registered = True})
        RegisteredUsers.Add(New Person With {.PersonID = 2, .Name = "Nicole Wilcox", .Registered = True})
        RegisteredUsers.Add(New Person With {.PersonID = 3, .Name = "Adrian Martinson", .Registered = False})
        RegisteredUsers.Add(New Person With {.PersonID = 4, .Name = "Nora Osborn", .Registered = False})
    Dim serializer As New JavaScriptSerializer()
    Dim serializedResult = serializer.Serialize(RegisteredUsers)
    ' Produces string value of: 
    ' [ 
    '     {"PersonID":1,"Name":"Bryon Hetrick","Registered":true}, 
    '     {"PersonID":2,"Name":"Nicole Wilcox","Registered":true}, 
    '     {"PersonID":3,"Name":"Adrian Martinson","Registered":false}, 
    '     {"PersonID":4,"Name":"Nora Osborn","Registered":false} 
    ' ] 

    Dim deserializedResult = serializer.Deserialize(Of List(Of Person))(serializedResult)
    ' Produces List with 4 Person objects
```

Comment: The question is tagged with C#.

Comment: Sorry , dont know C#, i thought to provide with a guidance as much as i could.