# pass C# arraylist to Javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, object, arraylist

I have an arrayList in C# where i store data of ip's and isp's and count as follows from a mysql table,

```
ArrayList conRc = new ArrayList();

while (readIp.Read())
{
    string ipVal = readIp.GetString(0);
    string ispVal = readIp.GetString(1);
    int conLvlVal = readIp.GetInt32(2);

    conRc.Add(new ConfidenceLvl(ipVal,ispVal,conLvlVal));
}
```

This is my ConfidenceLvl Class,

```
public class ConfidenceLvl
{
    private string ip;
    private string isp;
    private int conLvl;

    public string Ip
    {
        get { return ip; }
        set { ip = value; }
    }
    public string Isp
    {
        get { return isp; }
        set { isp = value; }
    }
    public int ConLvl
    {
        get { return conLvl; }
        set { conLvl = value; }
    }

    public ConfidenceLvl(string ipVal, string ispVal, int conLvlVal) {
        this.conLvl = conLvlVal;
        this.ip = ipVal;
        this.isp = ispVal;
    }
}
```

I wan to pass this to javascript so that i can make use of these value to create a chart through jqPlot. Please help on this one I used [this method](http://aspdotnetcodebook.blogspot.com/2008/04/passing-arraylist-to-javascript.html) to pass my values to javascript but it all goes as one string. I wan to take these values separately and work with them in javascript. Please help me. Thank you very much.

EDIT:
Thanks to  Dominik Kirschenhofer, I finally wound up with this after successfully parsing the to javascript. May i know how to manipulate these data? like getting records 1 by 1?? i tried to but none worked,

```
    <asp:HiddenField ID="correlate" value= "" runat="server" />
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        var jsonString = document.getElementById('correlate').value;
        var arr_from_json = JSON.parse(jsonString);

    </script>
```

The json string is as follows,

```
    [{"Ip":"0","Count":"10"},{"Ip":"1","Count":"11"},{"Ip":"2","Count":"12"},{"Ip":"3","Count":"13"},{"Ip":"4","Count":"14"},{"Ip":"5","Count":"15"},{"Ip":"6","Count":"16"},{"Ip":"7","Count":"17"},{"Ip":"8","Count":"18"},{"Ip":"9","Count":"19"}]
```

May i know how can i work with these records :)

EDIT: SOLVED IT

```
    <asp:HiddenField ID="correlate" value= "" runat="server" />
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        var jsonString = document.getElementById('correlate').value;
        jsonString = "{\"corrData\":" + jsonString + "}";
        var arr_from_json = JSON.parse(jsonString);
        alert(Number(arr_from_json.corrData[2].Ip)+1);
    </script>
```

I added corrData so that i can call it by an Integer Id like in an array. :) thanks for your help guys :) if there is better way..please let me know :)

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7846333/any-way-to-pass-an-object-from-c-sharp-code-behind-to-javascript,this may give you an idea...

Comment: Are you using webforms or mvc?

Comment: yea am using webforms :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are having a list or an array of fixed values in code behind which you want to use in js the easiers way is as explained in the link you have posted. Means serialize the list and store it in an hidden field. When you need to use it in js just deserialize and use it.

Serialization see: 
http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/pini_dayan/archive/2009/03/12/convert-objects-to-json-in-c-using-javascriptserializer.aspx

Deserialization:
[deserialize from json to javascript object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6487167/deserialize-from-json-to-javascript-object)

So what do you have to do:
1) Use a generic list.
2) Fill the list as needed.
3) Convert the list to an array => pretty easy using linq: myList.ToArray()
4) Serialize the array to a json string. See 1st link.
5) Place a hidden field on your page and set the json string as its value (code behind)
6) Whenever you need to use this array in js, just deserialize the value of the hidden field and use it. See 2nd link.

Comment: thank you for the reply. :) i will check on this and be back :)

Comment: hey..i tried researching this method..can you clarify..may be some links.. :) because i am new to the web development and i am kind of lost here.

Comment: wow that makes sense..ill do what you have said and get back :) thanks a bunch :)

Comment: I made an edit to the code..can you please help me on this last bit...i tried searching online like http://www.json.org/js.html but couldn't get any value out :( ..i want to retrieve records whenever i want from it :) thank you very much

Comment: okey, i solved it and added my solution to the question itself :) .. please let me know if there is a better way of doing it..many thanks for your advice and help :) much appreciated :)

Comment: Do you realy need this "corrData" stuff? I think you should be able to do "arr_from_json[0]" in your first edit. (Have not tried it yet)

Comment: Just created a little sample.
"arr_from_json[0].Ip" is working.
Normaly it helps to use Firebug (Firefox extension), DeveloperTool (integrated in IE7+) or the Chrome DeveloperTools to debug such scripts to see what state you have got!

Comment: okey..than k you very much !!!! i will try that out also :) :) thank you very much for your effort :) i just tried a sneaky way of doing it..thank you very much for pointing it that to me :)..

Answer (score 2):

If you're using ASP.net MVC then you can do the following. I have rewritten your code to use a generic list, instead of an ArrayList, The ArrayList is not strongly typed and is generally considered depreciated since generics came along with .net 2.0

Please note, that the following code will only work with a POST request, unless you modified it to include the `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet`

```
public class ConfidenceLvl
    {
        public string IpVal { get; set; }
        public string IspVal { get; set; }
        public string ConLvlVal { get; set; }
    }

    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            IList<ConfidenceLvl> levels = new List<ConfidenceLvl>();
            levels.Add(new ConfidenceLvl { IpVal = "129.123.123.123", ConLvlVal = "1", IspVal = "AOL" });
            levels.Add(new ConfidenceLvl { IpVal = "129.123.0.0", ConLvlVal = "3", IspVal = "CompuServe" });

            // Controlled json
            return Json(levels.Select(lv => new { title = lv.IspVal, ip = lv.IpVal }));

            // As it comes json
            //return Json(levels);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am using webforms, is there a difference between those two..sorry if this is a dumb question.but i am new to web development in asp.net

Comment: Yes, this method will not work for webforms. See the suggested link for a way of doing it with webforms: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/227624/asp-net-mvc-controller-actions-that-return-json-or-partial-html

Comment: I made an edit to the code..can you please help me on this last bit...i tried searching online like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4828207/how-to-use-a-json-file-in-javascript but couldn't get any value out :(