# JavaScript - Pass data from C# code

Tags: javascript, c#

I want to pass the data to `javascript` code from my code behind file (`C#`) and what I want at `javascript` side is something like the following

```
var data = [
    { 
        "date": "24-Apr-07", 
        "close": 93.24 
    }, 
    { 
        "date": "25-Apr-07", 
        "close": 95.35 
    }, 
    { 
        "date": "26-Apr-07", 
        "close": 98.84 
    }
];
```

I tried passing this as a string but failed since it considers the whole thing as a string only.

Is there any other option available ?

Comment: What web framework are you using? Classic ASP? ASP MVC?

Comment: asp.net web forms

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use http://www.newtonsoft.com/json.

```
Product product = new Product();
product.Name = "Apple";
product.Expiry = new DateTime(2008, 12, 28);
product.Sizes = new string[] { "Small" };

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(product);
// {
//   "Name": "Apple",
//   "Expiry": "2008-12-28T00:00:00",
//   "Sizes": [
//     "Small"
//   ]
// }
```

And in your JS you can deserialize it in this way:

```
var des_obj = JSON.parse( json_string );
```

Comment: You can also try this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7846333/any-way-to-pass-an-object-from-c-sharp-code-behind-to-javascript

Answer (score 0):

If you get the string at the javascript side, all you need to do is wrap the string in `JSON.parse()` to get your data.

```
var data =  JSON.parse('[
    {
        "date": "24-Apr-07",
        "close": 93.24
    }, {
        "date": "25-Apr-07",
        "close": 95.35
    }, {
        "date": "26-Apr-07",
        "close": 98.84
    }
]');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by Ajax call..

At Javascript side:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Default.aspx/GetData",
        data: dataValue,                
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("Request: " + XMLHttpRequest.toString() + "\n\nStatus: " + textStatus + "\n\nError: " + errorThrown);
        },
        success: function (result) {
            alert("We returned: " + result);
        }
    });
```

At Code behind:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string GetData()
{
   // return your data
}
```

When you return object from GetData() it automatically serialize the data. You can also use `return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that using [JsonConvert Class](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert.htm):

In C# code behind:

**C# ModelClass:**

```
public class RootObject
    {
        public string date { get; set; }
        public double close { get; set; }
    }
```

create a method for return json by giving `C#` object like this:

```
public class JSONConverter
    {
        public string Convert(List<RootObject> list)
        {
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list);
        }
    }
```

In your **ActionMethod**:

```
public void ActionResult()
{

     List<RootObject> list = repo.GetList(); // i assumed that you get list 
     //from repo
    ViewBag.modelList = JsonConverter.Convert(list);
    return View()
}
```

After all in C# View: **(NOTE: I assume that you are working in Razor view engine )**

```
<script>
var data = @ViewBag.modelList
<script>
```

Your json serialized c# array can be assigned to `data`.

Comment: Question is about ASP.NET web form application not MVC