# How to transfer a serialized JSON string from C# code behind to use in Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, telerik

The ultimate goal here is to populate fields of a  Bootstrap modal from an object in the C# code behind that has all the data I need. I serialized the object from the code behind, like this:

```
JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
sJSON = serializer.Serialize(aerationsystem.AerationSystem);
```

Now I want to reference that JSON in my Javascript function, like this:

```
</form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function fillModal() {
            var diameterValue = document.getElementById('diameter');            
            var aeration = <%# sJSON %>;
            diameterValue.innerText = aeration.dBinDiameter;
        }
    </script>
</asp:Content>
```

(I included that closing form tag and the closing asp:Content tag so you all could see where it was that I put this Javascript: at the very end of the file.)

However, when I call that Javascript function, this is what I see in the browser's debugger:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function fillModal() {
            var diameterValue = document.getElementById('diameter');            
            var aeration = ;
            diameterValue.innerText = aeration.dBinDiameter;
        }
    </script>
```

I got the idea from here: [Any way to pass an object from c# code behind to javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7846333/any-way-to-pass-an-object-from-c-sharp-code-behind-to-javascript)
But, the means of accessing that JSON variable does not work for me. I've tried moving my script, but when I do that, I get an error that says "The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>).". And I've tried other delimiters, like <%= %>, but I get the same errors depending on script placement. What am I doing wrong? How can I get that JSON string to show up in my Javascript function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you so much for taking the time to answer my question! I ended up solving the problem, with some inspiration from you all. Instead of using a `Literal` control, I ended up using a `<asp:HiddenField>` control on the page to store the value. Then, I pulled that its value into the Javascript variable.

The hidden field: `<asp:HiddenField ID="JsonLiteral" runat="server" />`

The code in the event that assigned the value:

```
JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
JsonLiteral.Value = serializer.Serialize(aerationsystem.AerationSystem);
```

And the JavaScript that finished the job:

```
function fillModal() 
    {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var diameter = document.getElementById('diameter');
            var control = document.getElementById('<%= JsonLiteral.ClientID%>');
            var aeration = JSON.parse(control.value);

            diameter.innerText = aeration.dBinDiameter;
        });
    }
```

(There's gonna be a lot more to it than just that one property, of course.)

Again, thank you all for you help, because I could not have done it without you!

Answer (score 0):

`<%# %>` is a binding block so you need call the `Page.DataBind()` method, whether in the `Page_Load` or the `Page_PreRender` event.

You also need to curate the string so the `JSON` text doesn't break your javascript:

```
var aeration = '<%# sJSON.Replace("'", "\'").Replace("\n", " ") %>';
```

Comment: I gave this a shot, and it solved the problem of the disappearing expression. However, sJSON is null to begin with, meaning that I'd need to delay calling Page.Databind() until sJSON had been filled with a JSON string. But the problem with that is that once the html has been parsed by the browser and the invalid delimiter has been removed, it never comes back. It just got too complicated.

Comment: Just call DataBind after setting sJSON, the replace is server side (over the sJSON variable) so the HTML is not being parsed yet, you could curate sJSON when you set the value and you won't need to do this

Comment: Yeah, that's way smarter. I'm gonna give that a shot. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`<%#  %>` syntax is for binding data from data source.

The easiest way is to use a Literal Server Control. It seems a bit weird inside script tag, but it does the job.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function fillModal() {
        var diameterValue = document.getElementById('diameter');
        var aeration = <asp:Literal id="JsonLiteral" runat="server"/>;
        diameterValue.innerText = aeration.dBinDiameter;
    }
</script>
```

### Code Behind

```
JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
JsonLiteral.Text = serializer.Serialize(aerationsystem.AerationSystem);
```

Comment: This seems like a cool idea, but the asp tag in there just breaks the JavaScript, and then the browser ignores it. Furthermore, if you try to just place the Literal control elsewhere on the page and pull its Text value, getElementById can't find it, no matter where you put it. The call to getElementbyId can be inside the jQuery `$(document).ready() function, and still not find it, even as it finds another element the line before. Truly baffling.

Comment: `place the Literal control elsewhere on the page and pull its Text value, getElementById can't find it` That is not in your original question, so I could not foresee other use cases. Anyhow, I'm glad that you figure it out.